# Why is the output of `echo true ? 'a' : true ? 'b' : 'c';` 'b'?

Tags: php

I have this bit of PHP code:

```
echo true ? 'a' : true ? 'b' : 'c';
```

The output of this is:

> b

But the output I expected was:

> a

Comment: __Don't__ nest ternary operators.... it makes your code unreadable, and is well documented as a bad practise because the logic doesn't execute as you'd expect

Comment: echo (true ? 'a' : (true ? 'b' : 'c'));

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-121

Comment: @MarkBaker: That's only because the condtional operator in php is right associative. Other languages are sane and the output is as expected.

Comment: @Femaref - It's still documented behaviour, and still a lot harder to read than nested ifs

Comment: @MarkBaker that's highly subjective. Personally I think the ternary ?: is easier to read than nested ifs if the conditions and the results are short.

Comment: A simple ternary is easier to read.... nested ternaries aren't, and are still subject to a lot of confusion over their behaviour (ergo this question among many).... and if I ever see nested ternaries used in code I'm reviewing for recruitment, then that person would never get a job in my company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code evaluates like this:

```
echo (true ? 'a' : true) ? 'b' : 'c';
```

it equivalent to:

```
echo (true) ? 'b' : 'c';
```

Then the result is `'b'`

Answer (score 11):

the ternary operator in php is left-associative.

You need to use

```
echo true ? 'a' : (true ? 'b' : 'c');
```