# How following script is evaluated?

Tags: php, logic

```
<?php echo true?'what':true?'will':'print?';?>
```

Above code outputs `will`.
I am not able to get logic behind it. Can anyone explain it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should work with braces: `echo true?'what':(true?'will':'print?');` this will output `what`. Probably the second if overrides the first if if there are no braces.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889373/quick-php-syntax-question

Comment: which one is true? according to @TiMESPLiNTER, ternary expressions get interpreted from right to left.  and according to `Justinas`, ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

Comment: Ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @DS9 Sorry wrote it the wrong way but did the examples the right way. I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the output of \`echo true ? 'a' : true ? 'b' : 'c';\` 'b'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751225/why-is-the-output-of-echo-true-a-true-b-c-b)

Answer (score 2):

You should work with braces:

```
echo true?'what':(true?'will':'print?');
```

this will output `what`. The second if overrides the first if if there are no braces. Because ternary expressions get interpreted from left to right. So without any braces set by you PHPs interpreter will interpret your statement as:

```
echo (true?'what':true)?'will':'print?';
```

**[According to PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) you should avoid stacking ternary expressions:**

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> Note:
>
> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:
>
> Example #4 Non-obvious Ternary Behaviour
>
> // however, the actual output of the above is 't'
>   // **this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right**
>
> // the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
>   **echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');**
>
> // here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
>   // in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
>   // second ternary expression.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator in PHP is left-associative. Your code evaluates like this:

```
echo (true ? 'what' : true) ? 'will' : 'print?';
```

This is equivalent to:

```
echo (true) ? 'will' : 'print?';
```

And thus, the result is 'will'. You should use the following:

```
echo true ? 'what' : (true ? 'will' : 'print?');
```

A related post can be found here: [Why is the output of `echo true ? 'a' : true ? 'b' : 'c';` 'b'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751225/why-is-the-output-of-echo-true-a-true-b-c-b)

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious: (as given in document)

Example:

`

```
on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

however, the actual output of the above is 't'
this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
second ternary expression.
```

`